# unable to add textviews and button below the list view id wrap content using

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my working xml code.. Now I want to add two text view and one button below the listview without changing the height of the list view.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/orderlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="#778899"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <include layout="@layout/footer" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `android:layout_above="@+id/layout"` in list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/orderlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#778899"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Total Price : 20.00"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buy" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working at my end  .try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="First Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/first"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="First Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sec"
            android:text="First Text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:divider="#778899"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout doesn't need orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `listview`  and added   `android:layout_above="@+id/layout"` in `listview` controll

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/orderlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="#778899"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change listview as below

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#778899"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do in this case is define the parameter `layout_weight` of your componentes according to your needs.

[What does layout weight means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)